# Angular mat-form-filed not finding "ngForm"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

In my Angular app: I want to switch from this form thats is working great:

```
<form autocomplete="off" #searchActor="ngForm"
    (ngSubmit)= submitForm(searchActor.value)
    class="ml-2 mr-2 my-auto">
    <input type="text" name="actorSearch"
        (ngModel)="model.searchActor">
 </form>
```

To this angular material one:

```
    <mat-form-field #searchActor="ngForm"
                        (ngSubmit)= submitForm(searchActor.value)
                        class="ml-2 mr-2 my-auto">
          <mat-label>Custom Search</mat-label>
            
          <input matInput type="text"
                          name="actorSearch"
                          placeholder="Ex. young, cartoon..." 
                          (ngModel)="model.searchActor">
          <button mat-button *ngIf="value" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="value=''">
            <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
          </button>
   </mat-form-field>
```

This is my imports:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
  ],
```

But whenever I load my app, I get this error:

[image: error log]

Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should leave form tag

```
<form autocomplete="off" #searchActor="ngForm" (ngSubmit)= submitForm(searchActor.value) class="ml-2 mr-2 my-auto">
```

And describe each field inside

It’s wrong syntax
<mat-form-field #searchActor="ngForm"

Something like this

```
<form novalidate #searchActor ="ngForm">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" name="myname" required [(ngModel)]="comment">
    <mat-error>Is required lol</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```